# MVVM binding enum values : lots of proxy properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemssource

I'm writing a ViewModel library which works with my WPF Custom Controls.
My problem is that my DomainModel has a large amount of Data Types:
Cd,Pens,Gadgets,Books,ecc.
All these Data Types are enumerated with an enum (I have more or less 1 hundred DataTypes), and each data Type corresponds to a DB table.

So the idea is to have a ViewModel library which exposes one property for each data type, thus my UI controls can directly bind the properties of my viewModel. The viewModel for each property return an ObservableCollection.
For instance, if I'd like to have my combo box populated with the "Gadgets" data, in my XAML I 'll have something like :

```
<my:XCombo ItemsSource="{Binding Gadgets}" .... />
```

and in my ViewModel I'll have :

```
public ObservableCollection<Gadgets> Gadgets
{
    get 
    {
        //get gadgets data from my domain model
        return _model.GetData(DataEnum.Gadgets);
    }
}
```

Now, in order to do that, I need in my ViewModel one property for each enumeration value, but I'd like to avoid to put 1 hundred property accessors. I'm lazy and this can be very error prone.
I know, in c#4 we have dynamic properties, so in this way I can avoid to write 100 property accessors, but I MUST use .net 3.5 which has no dynamic properties, i cannot use .net 4 ;(

Is there anyone who has already had this problem or any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you're lazy, how did you end up with this domain design?

Comment: Why does your ViewModel need 100 collections of objects? ViewModels should reflect the View, so if your `GadgetsView` contains only a ComboBox for Gadgets, the ViewModel should have only an `ObservableCollection<Gadgets>`, not `ObservableCollection<Cds>`, `ObservableCollection<Pens>`, etc

Comment: I should put one property for each data type because I'm writing a view model library. It's an API for writing applications using my data  infrastructure. I can't know what data requires each app that uses my API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use an indexer property which returns the respective data

```
public IList this[DataEnum type]
{
     return _model.GetData(type);
}
```

Then bind it using that:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding [Gadgets]}"
```

Comment: *sigh*, beat me. Exactly my approach, too.

Comment: @flq At least that means it probably isn't such an outlandish idea :)

Comment: Wooow, I don't thinked that it was possible to bind an Indexer Property!!! Thank you very much. It seems the best approach for the moment.

Comment: @user1070316: You're welcome, glad it helped! The [`Path` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) covers everything you can bind to, it might be of interest. (Also, if that sufficiently answers your question you could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) it.)